# add to existing object in json array Rails 3

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3

```
  render :json mailbox.inbox.as_json(:include => [
      {:messages => {:only => [:body]}}, 
      {:recipients => {:only => [:Firstname,:Surname]}}
    ])
```

produces the following output from my Rails controller:

```
[
    {
        "conversation":
        {
            "subject":"Subject for conversation 2",
            "messages" :[
                {"body":"Message 1"},
                {"body":"Message 2"} 
            ],
            "recipients": [
                {"Firstname":"James","Surname":"Smith"},
                {"Firstname":"John","Surname":"Doe"} 
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

What I would like to do is to add a **current_user** key:value pair to each **conversation** object so the out sample would look like this:

```
[
    {
        "conversation":
        {
            "subject":"Subject for conversation 2",
            "messages" :[
                {"body":"Message 1"},
                {"body":"Message 2"},

            ],
            "recipients": [
                {"Firstname":"James","Surname":"Smith"},
                {"Firstname":"John","Surname":"Doe"} 
            ],
            "current_user" :[
                {"id":10}
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I don't have access to the conversation model in question (it's running off the mailboxer gem) so can't override as_json.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: have you consider using jbuilder, or create your json by another way? as_json can't add an arbitrary value, the most arbitrary is the return of a method call, using the keyword `:method` as you can see in [apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json)

Comment: I did try the :methods call on as_json as per the apidock but I assume that the method needs to reside in the Conversation model which I don't have access to.  I'll look up jbuilder now, thanks

Comment: Yes, you assumed it right.

Comment: jbuilder seems to be exactly what I'm looking for thank you.  Ryan Bates has a nice simple webcast on it too: http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, formalizing the comments.

By looking the [apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json) of json_as, you can see that the only way to include arbitrary data is to add a method that retunrs the data you want to use in the model.

Since it is not the best thing to do in many ways and you don't have access to the model, one way out to customize your json is using a popular gem called [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder), that allows you to create a more complex json.